# link not found, 404 error

Tags: jquery, json, hyperlink, request

I am doing a small school project that is basically a web app that searches nearby restaurants by keywords = restaurant and the specific cuisine that the user chooses. However, I have a problem when getting the website of the place and putting it in "a" tag and when I press the link to test it, it says that the page cannot be found. But the link works perfectly when I copy and paste the link in a new tab in the browser.

This is the jquery that deals with the json output of my request:

```
var restaurantContactDetails = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference="+restaurant_reference+"&key=API_KEY";
$.getJSON(restaurantContactDetails,function(jsondata){
    $("#restaurant_contact").html("Contacts: " + "<p> UK: " + jsondata.result.formatted_phone_number+ ","+ " International: " + jsondata.result.international_phone_number+"</p>");
    //$("#restaurant_contact").append("<p> International: " + jsondata.result.international_phone_number+"</p>");
    var website = jsondata.result.website;
    //alert(website);
    console.log(website);
    $("#restaurant_website").append("<a href=website >" + website+"</a>");
    for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(jsondata.result.reviews).length;i++){                
        $("#Client_reviews").append("<p class=rust_reviews>"+"<h4 class=text-success>"+jsondata.result.reviews[i].author_name+"</h4>"+"<pre>"+jsondata.result.reviews[i].text+"</pre>");
    }
});
```

I should mention that the place website sometimes is a specific link like this:
http://www.premierinn.com/en/hotel/ABEPTI/aberdeen-city-centre?cmp=GLBC 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this. ` $("#restaurant_website").append("<a href=" + website + ">" + website+"</a>");`

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thank you soo much, codehx! I guess I should have been more careful when constructing this append! Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $("#restaurant_website").append("<a href=" + website + ">" + website+"</a>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem in this line

```
"<a href=website >" + website+"</a>
```

as `website` is a variable which contains URL it should be like this

```
"<a href="+ website + ">" + website+"</a>"
```

example.

```
$("#restaurant_website").append("<a href=" + website + ">" + website+"</a>");
```

Comment: Great, I see now where the problem was :)